# Installable trigger stopped working in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have installable trigger in Apps Script, which triggers when cell value is changed (so on sheet edit), but suddenly stopped launching the associated script, when a cell value is changed.

onEdit(e) simple trigger works in Apps Script, but installable not

```
function myOnedit(e) {

    Browser.msgBox("test");

}
```

When cell value is changed, trigger should run the script "myOnedit", and show "test" on the screen.

Comment: Welcome. Do you mean that you have two OnEdit scripts - one is simple, and the other (shown above) is installable?

Comment: I tested your code just now both with an installable and with a simple `onEdit()` trigger (separately), and both attempts worked as intended. you could try deleting and creating the installable trigger again. Do you have any other triggers set up for your script?

Comment: From my point of view, it looks that Google crashed the file I'm using, so it doesn't accept installable triggers anymore, just simple triggers. I received the script report on Sunday with some errors while executing installable trigger during the week, and on Monday trhe trigger stopped working. I tried to delete it and set it up again, but doesn't work again

Comment: I just want to make sure that you do NOT have two scripts that are both operating as "onEdit". That is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Do you have one or more scripts that are changing your document or script properties using the `PropertiesService`? I had a similar issue, but it went away so I can't test it and prove it's the problem until I see it again. I'm thinking that running a script with `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().deleteAllProperties()` may solve the problem. Also, you may want to check that everything you're writing to properties is properly formed.